# how can i explain my project in interview

Tags: interviewing, fresher

i did my project in steel plant 1 year ago.mostly we visited all departments and see the process.i feel like we waste more time there,because we are not completing my project.my project is about conveyors.but we gathered information in internet and some books.we have only 30 to 40 % knowledge in conveyors.so if interviewer ask to describe our project,what i have to tell and how to start...????

Comment: I for one wasn't there, so I can't really describe your project to you.

Comment: Was this a university project? Maybe you can edit the question a little bit with a ltitle more structure to convey what you did and what you're trying to explain. Being able to formulate it here is probably 80% of what you need to be able to do in an interview.

Comment: For starters, distinguish what you learned. You question right now is only written as a complaint. Therefore I am not surprised that the question is also a horrible dump of text. Please [edit], put some capitals and spaces in.

Comment: If you write your resume the way you have written the question here, you don't even have to worry about explaining your project in the interview - because you won't be invited for one! I am okay with people making spelling and grammar mistakes (if English is not their native language), but those unnecessary extra punctuation marks (...????) make you come across as a immature kid, not a professional.

Answer (score 3):

**Short answer:** Practice!

I used to tell students at university to come up with an [elevator pitch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elevator_pitch) for their final year or Master's projects.  The point being is that if you happened to be caught in the elevator with someone like the CEO or a professor who could fund your project, you need to be able to explain your research to a casual observer in less than 30 seconds.

So like anything else, this takes time to draft and practice.  If you can't tell it in a couple of sentences, it's too detailed and complex.  What you're trying to do is to simply give a brief overview.  If you have "hooked" your audience, they will press you for more information.

Then once you have worked it out, practice it many times so that it comes out naturally and you are comfortable with it.  When you're in a pressure situation like an interview, it will just easily fall from your mouth :)

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Jane S in building an elevator pitch. Based on the research you have conducted on your interviewing company, tailor the pitch to the employers needs.

For example, emphasise how similar the steel plant is to your target industry, that you developed your research skills, that you hit the ground running by meeting useful contacts and asking good questions, the contacts you met have contributed to your professional network by connecting with you on LinkedIn etc.